# How do I make the road grid for new towns fit the existing road grid?

Tags: openttd

Under `Settings > World generation > Road layout for new towns`, it is possible to specify what the road network will look like. The default is 3x3 grids. When starting a new game, all towns on the map will fit perfectly into a grid such that even when cities merge, the road network will still be consistently composed of 3x3 grids everywhere.

However, when a user founds a new town, the road network of the new town is not guaranteed to perfectly fit into the existing 3x3 grid layout.

How can I found new towns while making sure that the road network of the new town fits perfectly into the existing road network?

Answer (score 0):

Last I checked, you are able to click where you want to found the town. The center tile of a town is always going to be a road tile. Hence, the solution is simply to force the issue manually:

1. Build the road network out to the location where you want to found the town. Build the network one or two blocks out.
2. Delete the center tile. You end up with something like this;

   ```
        =
    +===+===+
    =   =   =
    =   =   =
    =   =   =
   =+===x===+=
    =   =   =
    =   =   =
    =   =   =
    +===+===+
        =
   ```
3. Found the town indicated in the marked `x` spot.